# How does a virtual machine get the space

Tags: virtual-machine, disk-space

I have just created a win7 virtual machine on a win8 host. I assigned the client machine more than 30 GB of disk space.
Does that mean I have 30 GB less to use on my host? I am asking because it looks like the usable space on my host machine didn't seem to change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 options:
1 - you preallocate all space, in which case the space is substracted from start from your host drive.
2 - you don't preallocate (what you did) which means space will be substracted only if you actually use it. So when you copy something in the guest/VM, that exact size needed will dynamically be removed from host.